# How to Create log files in PowerShell

Tags: batch-file, powershell-2.0

I am currently switching to powershell from batch and working out how to do all of the things I usually do in batch in powershell.

One that has me stumped is logging what has been done in a script.

Batch:

```
echo "Move the csv to the archive dir" >> log.txt
move C:\Temp\file1.csv C:\Temp\Archive\ >> log.txt
echo. >> log.txt
```

The above would move file1 to the archive directory and write the fact that a file was moved to a log file.

I am finding it hard to find the equivalent of doing this in powershell whilst keeping it as simple as ">>" in batch.

Is there a simple cmdlet to handle logging?

Thank you for your help.

Comment: look this post [Powershell and writing files] (http://blogs.technet.com/b/gbordier/archive/2009/05/05/powershell-and-writing-files-how-fast-can-you-write-to-a-file.aspx)

Comment: Very helpful article. I have tested some basic logging using StreamWriter and it works well. Thanks for the link.

Answer (score 0):

Below is a simple example of the logging if anyone is interested. I will just improve this post as I work out more pieces of my Logging puzzle.

```
$stream = [System.IO.StreamWriter] "C:\Temp\test.txt"

$array=1..10
$array | %{ $stream.WriteLine($_) }

$array=11..100
$array | %{ $stream.WriteLine($_) }

$stream.close()
```